# Parsing arrays in PHP

Tags: php, array

I am developing a PHP application and I have the following array: **`print_r($array)`**

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [can_see_custom_stories] => 1
        [name] => caitlinhamm
        [display] =>
        [type] => 3
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [can_see_custom_stories] => 1
        [name] => vladhq
        [display] =>
        [type] => 0
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => interne [display] => Vlad [type] => 0 )
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => frankiedoyle30 [display] => [type] => 0 )
    [4] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => ayyeitskenzie03 [display] => [type] => 0 )
    [5] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => laynedawwg [display] => Layne [type] => 0 )
    [6] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => sarah.murphy225 [display] => [type] => 1 )
    [7] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => rath1 [display] => Rathwaan [type] => 0 )
    [8] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => brittanyyo [display] => Brit [type] => 0 )
    [9] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => teamsnapchat [display] => Snapchat [type] => 0 )
    [10] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => falconpunch1209 [display] => Colin Parker [type] => 0 )
    [11] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => shawn_bonds [display] => Shawn Bonds [type] => 0 )
    [12] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => chrisknowles [display] => Chris [type] => 0 )
    [13] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => pypereronipizza [display] => [type] => 0 )
    [14] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => wannaknow123 [display] => [type] => 0 )
    [15] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => zainthugmalik [display] => Zain [type] => 1 )
    [16] => stdClass Object ( [can_see_custom_stories] => 1 [name] => quinlanjade [display] => Quin [type] => 1 )
)
```

I want to pass it some how easily without any of the `foreach()` statements.

So the array is `$snapchat->getFriends()`. Is it possible for me to do something like:

```
$user = 'shawn_bonds';
$display = $snapchat->getFriends()->name['shawn_bonds']->display;
```

How would I get a display name based on the original name?

Thanks!

Comment: how is this a super user question?

Answer (score 1):

Vlad, you need to provide index of the accessed element of the array. For example:

```
$snapchat->getFriends()[1]->name;
```

To find index you can use `foreach`. I know you say you do not want to use it, but I believe this is the best way find proper array index (considering your array consists of objects).

Otherwise it is not possible to access array's element. Here is [question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4742903/1418463) about almost same thing.